# Creating sub-fields within a field

Tags: 7, entities

I am using the profile2 module in Drupal 7. I have created a field using the check box/radio widget that has 2 options and both options can be checked. How would I be able to create a sub-field that will show another checkbox/radio widget with options depending on what was checked in the main field?

Answer (score 2):

For Drupal 6, there was [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields).

There is no Drupal 7 version yet, but there is an [issue](http://drupal.org/node/658012) which links to [field conditional state](http://drupal.org/node/1073388) which at this point is only a sandbox project but seems to be widely used already.

Comment: There is also a [development snapshot for Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/1137614) of Conditional Fields.